# Can we find the Galois group of the splitting field of any polynomial, practically?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and $\mathbb Q_p$ be the $p$-adic field. Consider an minimal polynomial of $\alpha \in \mathbb Q_p$ $$f(x)=x^{p^2}+g_1(p)x^{p^2-1}+\cdots+g_{p^2-1}(p)x+g_{p^2}(p),$$
where the coefficients $g_i(p)$ are functions of $p$, the prime number. So we know the coefficients in terms of $p$.

- Assume that I know the coefficients $g_i(p)$ for all $i$.

> Can we find the Galois group, in practical, for such higher degree polynomial ?

For particular cases, e.g., take $g_i(p)=p^i$ and $p=2$, then the polynomial looks simple as $$h(x)=x^{4}+2x^{3}+4x^2+8x+16,$$   whose Galois grup can be computed.

But suppose, I want to calculate the general Galois group for all $p$, e.g., $$r(x)=x^{p^2}+px^{p^2-1}+\cdots+p^{p^2-1}x+p^{p^2}.$$
Is it possible to calculate the Galois group of $r(x)$, just looking at the pattern of the coefficients ?

I found [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/explicit_methods_in_number_theory/nf_galois_groups.html) that Sage/PARI can compute Galois of number field.

Thanks

Comment: The Galois group of $h(x)$ is $S_4$, as SageMath [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzz1rNJzCnISLRTsFXwK81NSi1yy0zNSdGoiDPRNtKqiDPWNgGSRtoWWhXaJpq8XO5Add566Yk5-ZnF8elF-aUFGiBRAP-_FLI=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: For odd primes $p$, your polynomial factors into a linear factor and two polynomials of degree $(p^2-1)/2$. If these last two polynomials are irreducible, their Galois group is cyclic. In general I do not see a way of controlling the number of factors.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer, thanks. So the only way is to check the Galois group by varying the prime $p$. But even in that case, consider a higher degree polynomial, say, $f(x)=x^{125}+5x^5+5x^2+1$. How to find the Galois group of its splittng field. I think Sage will also fail.

Comment: Fact correct: my 1st comment was not correct. The SageMath output was `Galois group 4T5 (S4) with order 24 of x^4 + 2*x^3 + 4*x^2 + 8*x + 4`. Can someone explain what does it mean ?

Comment: Shouldn't the last coefficient of $h$ be $16$? As for "Sage will also fail": Do it by hand. Divide by $p^{p^2}$ and introduce a new variable.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer, yes you are right that constant coefficient is $16$.

Comment: You can look up a Galois group label like `4T5` in the [LMFDB's database of Galois groups](https://www.lmfdb.org/GaloisGroup/) to get more information about the group, such as its common name ($S_4$ in this case), various properties, and lists of field extensions with that Galois group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few comments. Consider $f(x) = x^{p^2} + px^{p^2-1} + \ldots + p^{p^2}$.
Dividing through by $p^{p^2}$ and setting $X = x/p$ we obtain the polynomial $g(x) = X^{p^2} + X^{p^2-1} + \ldots + X + 1 = \frac{X^{p^2+1}-1}{X-1}$. For $p = 2$, this is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_5(X) = X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1$, whose Galois group over the rationals (sa well as over ${\mathbb Q}_2$) is the cyclic group of order $4$.

If $p$ is odd, then $g(X) = (X+1)(X^{p^2-1} + X^{p^2-3} + \ldots + X^2 + 1)$. Therefore, with $m = \frac{p^2-1}2$,
$$ g(X) = (X+1)(X^m + X^{m-1} + \ldots + X + 1)(X^m - X^{m-1} + X^{m-2} \mp \ldots - X + 1). $$
Since these are cyclotomic polynomials, the Galois groups of the irreducible factors of $g$ are cyclic.

For $p = 3, 5, 9, 11, 15, 19$, the factors of degree $m = (p^2-1)/2$ are irreducible and have cyclic Galois group.

For $p = 7, 13, 17$, the factors of degree $m = (p^2-1)/2$ are reducible.

Comment: Excellent. Cyclotomic polynomials are always irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, so can you please explain your last line ?

Comment: By a cyclotomic polynomial I meant a factor of $x^n-1$.

Comment: Thanks. For prime $p>2$, I have the irreducible polynomial $\left(x^{p^2}-a\right)^{p^3}-p^{p^3+1}x+p^{p^3}a \in \mathbb Q_p[a]$, where $a$ is known and given by $a=p^{\frac{p^3+1}{p^5-1}}$. It is irreducible I have checked. Can we talk about the Galois group of its splitting field, at least for $p=3$  ?

Comment: I got stuck with the above polynomial. Can its Galois group be cyclic ?

Comment: sorry for typo. the polynomial is over the field $\mathbb Q_p(a)$ i.e., it belongs to $\mathbb Q_p(a)[x]$